# Java most efficiently handle non-existing JSON object properties

Tags: java, json, performance, null, processing-efficiency

I am trying to have my code catch and handle non-existing object properties.

To handle this error I created below code. Which I find very inefficient, clumsy and ugly. What am I supposed to do when I have to check more properties? copy paste the code for each property? It's repetitive, clumsy and slow most of all.

My code iterates over 40,000 items+, which I aim to do as fast as possible. Continuesly checking for object properties null value doesn't help the processing time.

```
String description;
       if(items.getDescription() != null){
           description = items.getDescription();
       } else{
           description = null;
       }
```

**The Question:**

How can I **most efficiently** check for **multiple** properties their existence (preferable also empty `""`)?

I read into setting string default values with annotations or something. Use Java's assert function (not entirely sure what it does). All other "solutions" I found were the same as I created above. `!=null`.

**Background-info:**

the object is created from a serialized JSON object. This object comes from an API over HTTP web request. I have no control over the api thus can't change its output. I have to check for possible null, empty and non-existing properties.

edit: providing currently used code.

```
JSONObject httpJSONObject = new JSONObject(result);
            itemRoot items = new Gson().fromJson(httpJSONObject.toString(), itemRoot.class);
            /*String description;
            if(items.getDescription() != null){
                description = items.getDescription();
            } else{
                description = null;
            }*/

            String query = "INSERT INTO item VALUES('" + items.getName().replaceAll("'","''") +
                    "','" + items.getDescription() +
```

Nullpointer error at very last line `items.getDescription`. I checked. When I use the `!=null` and set a value then everything is, of course, fine.

Comment: If you know what the fields are, use a databind library like Jackson or GSON.

Comment: I am already using GSON. but Im not sure how this could solve my problem.

Comment: I assume you know what the fields are then... So look at example 3 -> 5 [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Comment: @stelar7 that's exactly what im using. But I get a nullpointer error when im  trying to use items.getDescription() in the DB query because its null.

Comment: @stelar7 i included the Gson code im using in my post as edit.